# How can i get token from identity server 4 from angular js?

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

1. I can get get access token from postman oauth 2. Same way i was
   tried to generate token in angular js with redirect url, client id
   ... etc.
2. But i not able to do and also i don't know how?
3. I was created identity server 4 API sample with auth server. Now i
   want to get token  from my angular app.

[image: In this image i used postman callback url and my identity auth server with client id ,secret]

[image: Here my identity server auth url navigate in postman browser after give credentials can get token]

[image: Finally got token]

But i need this flow in angular js.
I tried this below  code

```
angular.module("trainingApp")
.controller('loginController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    function login(){
        var client_id="testproduct";
        var client_secret="test@123";
        var scope="testAPI";
        var redirect_uri="http://localhost:9000";
        var response_type="token";
        var url="http://localhost:1215/connect/authorize?scope="+scope+"&client_id="+client_id+"&client_secret="+client_secret+"&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000"+redirect_uri+"&grant_type=authorization_code"+
       "&response_type="+response_type;
        window.location.replace(url);
    };
    login();
}])
```

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:1215/connect/…' from origin 'localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

But i am get UI for Login. Help ???? :)

Comment: I think you are using the wrong scopes for loging in with Angular.  I am pritty sure you should be working with something like this response_type = 'id_token token';
    scope = 'openid profile';    It should be an implicit client.

Comment: @DaImTo Yes but i am using code as response type and its working in postman right ? . So I need solution

Comment: Yes but postman uses a different type of login than what angular should be using.  Thats what the token types denote.   Loging in using say asp .net is also a diffrent type.  The clients are different and the methods for login are different

Comment: @DaImTo I am getting this error => Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:1215/connect/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=nuvuwproduct&redirect_uri=&scope=openid,profile,email,NuVuwAPI&nonce=N0.133015638746789121543926778415&state=15439267784150.7956081030684627' from origin 'http://localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: For a client side browser app you should use implicit flow which is “id_token token” response type. As for the CORS error, your sample code doesn’t include any XmlHTTPResquest code but if you are doing a request via that mechanism you’ll need to add the origin to the allowed list on the client defined in identityserver4.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with the authorize endpoint redirect but you're doing it the hard way.

Check out the oidc-client-js library, it does everything you need and there are even samples for Angular.

https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js

Comment: thanks but i need this for angualar js vertion  platform .

Comment: This library is framework agnostic, what doesn't it do that you need?